# How to use OR in a list comprehension IF condition

Tags: python-3.x, list, if-statement

I need to filter out all columns that don't end with a _y or _x.

```
merged_hdi_aidg=df_HDI.merge(df_FDAC_CA, on='iso3_codes')
merged_hdi_aidg.columns
```

Index(['Country_x', '1990', '1991', '1992', '1993', '1994', '1995', '1996',
'1997', '1998', '1999', '2000', '2001_x', '2002_x', '2003_x', '2004_x',
'2005_x', '2006_x', '2007_x', '2008_x', '2009_x', '2010_x', '2011_x',
'2012_x', '2013_x', '2014_x', '2015_x', '2016_x', '2017_x', '2018_x',
'iso3_codes', 'Country_y', '2001_y', '2002_y', '2003_y', '2004_y',
'2005_y', '2006_y', '2007_y', '2008_y', '2009_y', '2010_y', '2011_y',
'2012_y', '2013_y', '2014_y', '2015_y', '2016_y', '2017_y', '2018_y',
'2019', '2020'],
dtype='object')

```
drop_columns=[]
[drop_columns.append(column) for column in merged_hdi_aidg.columns if ('_y' not in column or '_x' not in column)];
drop_columns
```

['Country_x',
'1990',
'1991',
'1992',
'1993',
'1994',
'1995',
'1996',
'1997',
'1998',
'1999',
'2000',
'2001_x',
'2002_x',
'2003_x',
'2004_x',
'2005_x',
'2006_x',
'2007_x',
'2008_x',
'2009_x',
'2010_x',
'2011_x',
'2012_x',
'2013_x',
'2014_x',
'2015_x',
'2016_x',
'2017_x',
'2018_x',
'iso3_codes',
'Country_y',
'2001_y',
'2002_y',
'2003_y',
'2004_y',
'2005_y',
'2006_y',
'2007_y',
'2008_y',
'2009_y',
'2010_y',
'2011_y',
'2012_y',
'2013_y',
'2014_y',
'2015_y',
'2016_y',
'2017_y',
'2018_y',
'2019',
'2020']

Comment: Hi Clayton, did our solutions help you?

Comment: yup, they all did. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it the other way around, select those that contain _x and _y:

Example data

```
merged_hdi_aidg = pd.DataFrame({'x1_y':[1,2], 'x1_x':[1,3], 'x1_z':[0,0]})
```

Use `str.contains`:

```
merged_hdi_aidg.loc[:, merged_hdi_aidg.columns.str.contains('|'.join(['_y', '_x']))]
```

In case you want to be sure to only capture _x and _y at the end of the columnnames, use `endswith`:

```
merged_hdi_aidg.loc[:, merged_hdi_aidg.columns.str.endswith(('_x','_y'))]
```

Comment: this also solved my problem! It also led me to ask why do you need ,join() and can't use just a list? I tried the list and got an error... The way you presented it works fine though, thanks!

Comment: The join part `'|'.join(['_y', '_x'])` makes it `'_y|_x'` which is the format you need in `str.contains` to test for multiple strings. So the join part allows you to put in a list as `'|'.join(yourlist)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible way. I slightly modified your code.
Steps

- Make a set of all columns
- Make a set of all columns you wish to discard ..(that have the
  patterns in them)
- Get a difference of 1 and 2.
- Done

```
merged_hdi_aidg=df_HDI.merge(df_FDAC_CA, on='iso3_codes')
AllColumns = set(merged_hdi_aidg.columns)
drop_columns=[]
[drop_columns.append(column) for column in merged_hdi_aidg.columns if ('_y' in column or '_x' in column)];
drop_columns = set(drop_columns)
ColumnsThatYouWant = AllColumns - drop_columns
print(ColumnsThatYouWant)
```

It gives the following output

```py
{'1998', '1992', '1999', '2020', '1993', '1991', '1990', 'iso3_codes', '2000', '1995', '1997', '2019', '1996', '1994'}
```

May be you want to convert it back to a list or something.
By the way you are not checking for '_x' or '_y' in the end of a column name. You are checking only if they are present anywhere in the column name. May be you want to fix that too.

Comment: Thanks! This code works fine but gives me the columns which I wanted to drop rather than the ones I want to keep. I just had to reorganize it a bit and it worked fine!

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be like this :

```
x = ['Country_x', '1990', '1991', '1992', '1993', '1994', '1995', '1996', '1997', '1998', '1999', '2000', '2001_x', 
     '2002_x', '2003_x', '2004_x', '2005_x', '2006_x', '2007_x', '2008_x', '2009_x', '2010_x', '2011_x', '2012_x', 
     '2013_x', '2014_x', '2015_x', '2016_x', '2017_x', '2018_x', 'iso3_codes', 'Country_y', '2001_y', '2002_y', 
     '2003_y', '2004_y', '2005_y', '2006_y', '2007_y', '2008_y', '2009_y', '2010_y', '2011_y', '2012_y', '2013_y', 
     '2014_y', '2015_y', '2016_y', '2017_y', '2018_y', '2019', '2020']


columns_to_take = [i for i in x if i.endswith('_x') or i.endswith('_y')]

print("columns_to_take = ", columns_to_take)

columns_to_drop = [i for i in x if (not i.endswith('_x')) and (not i.endswith('_y'))]

print("columns_to_drop = " , columns_to_drop)
```